# Average of multiple files in shell

Tags: shell, unix, awk, mean

I want to calculate the average of 15 files:- ifile1.txt, ifile2.txt, ....., ifile15.txt. Number of columns and rows of each file are same. Part of the data looks as

```
ifile1.txt      ifile2.txt       ifile3.txt
3  5  2  2 .    1  2  1  3 .    4  3  4  1 .
1  4  2  1 .    1  3  0  2 .    5  3  1  5 .
4  6  5  2 .    2  5  5  1 .    3  4  3  1 .
5  5  7  1 .    0  0  1  1 .    4  3  4  0 .
.  .  .  . .    .  .  .  . .    .  .  .  . .
```

I would like to find over a new file which will show the average of these 15 fils.

```
ofile.txt
2.66   3.33  2.33 2      . (i.e. average of 3 1 4, average of 5 2 3 and so on)
2.33   3.33  1    2.66   .
3      5     4.33 1.33   .
3      2.33  4    0.66   .
.      .     .    .      .
```

I was trying with following, but getting error

```
awk'{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)} rows=FNR;cols=NF} END 
{for (i=1; i<=rows; i++){for (j=1; j<=cols; j++) 
s+=$i;print $0,s/NF;s=0}}' ifile* > ofile.txt
```

Comment: The error message may help someone answer you.

Comment: Why are you trying to access `$0` and `$i` in the `END` block? That runs after you finish reading all the files, there's no current record to process.

Comment: As written (`awk'{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)} rows=FNR;cols=NF} END …`), you  get 'command not found' as the error because you must leave a space between `awk` and the script `'…'`.  When you fix that, you start getting into problems because there are two `}` and only one `{` on the first line of the script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As written:

```
awk'{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)} rows=FNR;cols=NF} END
…
```

you get 'command not found' as the error because you must leave a space between `awk` and the script inside the quotes.  When you fix that, you start getting into problems because there are two `}` and only one `{` on the first line of the script.

When you get around to tackling the problem, you're going to need a 2D array, indexed by line number and column number, summing the values from the files.  You'll also need to know the number of files processed, and the number of columns.  You can then arrange to iterate over the 2D array in the END block.

```
awk 'FNR == 1 { nfiles++; ncols = NF }
     { for (i = 1; i < NF; i++) sum[FNR,i] += $i
       if (FNR > maxnr) maxnr = FNR
     }
     END {
         for (line = 1; line <= maxnr; line++)
         {
             for (col = 1; col < ncols; col++)
                  printf "  %f", sum[line,col]/nfiles;
             printf "\n"
         }
     }' ifile*.txt
```

Given the three data files from the question:

**ifile1.txt**

```
3 5 2 2
1 4 2 1
4 6 5 2
5 5 7 1
```

**ifile2.txt**

```
1 2 1 3
1 3 0 2
2 5 5 1
0 0 1 1
```

**ifile3.txt**

```
4 3 4 1
5 3 1 5
3 4 3 1
4 3 4 0
```

The script I showed produces:

```
  2.666667  3.333333  2.333333
  2.333333  3.333333  1.000000
  3.000000  5.000000  4.333333
  3.000000  2.666667  4.000000
```

If you want to control the number of decimal places to 2, then use `%.2f` in place of `%f`.

Comment: I don't know if it is just a `GNU awk` thing (which I use), but the value of `FNR` and `NF` is still valid in the `END{ }` block - so that would save the need to handle those vars separately (in `GNU awk`  at least) . +1

Comment: It's shouldn't be a feature of GNU `awk` only; the information for the last line of the last file is probably available in POSIX standard `awk` too.  That said, I probably would beef up the code to spot improper input files — too many or too few columns, or too many or too few lines.  I simply don't trust users, including myself, not to abuse the system.  GIGO is fine, but spotting that the garbage is coming in can head off problems.

Comment: Check the POSIX specification for [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html); it explicitly says that both FNR and NF retain the values from the last line of the last file in the END block.

Comment: Why is the result lacking a column? How can this be fixed to show all columns?

Comment: @And — The missing column is because I used `i < NF` instead of `i <= NF`.  The fix is that complicated.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ { head -n1 ifile1.txt; paste ifile*.txt;} | awk 'NR==1{d=NF; next;} {for (i=1;i<=d;i++) {s=0; for (j=i;j<=NF;j+=d) s+=$j; printf "%.2f%s",s/(NF/d),j==NF+d?"\n":"\t";}}'
2.67    3.33    2.33    2.00
2.33    3.33    1.00    2.67
3.00    5.00    4.33    1.33
3.00    2.67    4.00    0.67
```

This script computes each row and prints the results before moving on to the next row.  Because of this, the script does not need to hold all the data in memory at once.  This is important if the data files are large.

#### How it works

- `{ head -n1 ifile1.txt; paste ifile*.txt;}`

  This prints just the first line of `ifile1.txt`.  Then, the `paste` command causes it to print the first row of all files merged, then the second row merged, and so on:

  ```
  $ paste ifile*.txt
  3  5  2  2      1  2  1  3      4  3  4  1
  1  4  2  1      1  3  0  2      5  3  1  5
  4  6  5  2      2  5  5  1      3  4  3  1
  5  5  7  1      0  0  1  1      4  3  4  0
  ```
- `|`

  The pipe symbol causes the output of the above commands to be sent as input to awk.  Addressing each of the awk commands in turn:
- `NR==1{d=NF; next;}`

  For the first row, we save the number of columns in variable `d`.  Then, we skip the rest of the commands and start over on the `next` line of input.
- `for (i=1;i<=d;i++) {s=0; for (j=i;j<=NF;j+=d) s+=$j; printf "%.2f%s",s/(NF/d),j==NF+d?"\n":"\t";}`

  This adds up the numbers from the respective files and prints the average.

#### As a multiline script:

```
{
    head -n1 ifile1.txt
    paste ifile*.txt
} | 
awk '
    NR==1 {d=NF; next;}

    {
        for (i=1;i<=d;i++)
        {
            s=0; for (j=i;j<=NF;j+=d)
                s+=$j;
            printf "%.2f%s",s/(NF/d),j==NF+d?"\n":"\t";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to save the sum the fields into an array when you're reading the original files. You can't access `$0` and `i` in the `END` block, since there's no input line then.

```
awk '{rows=FNR; cols=NF; for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { total[FNR, i] += $i }}
     FILENAME != lastfn { count++; lastfn = FILENAME }
     END { for (i = 1; i <= rows; i++) { 
                for (j =  1; j <= cols; j++) {
                    printf("%s ", total[i, j]/count)
                }
                printf("\n")
            }
        }' ifile* > ofile.txt
```