# Average of multiple files without considering different kind of missing values

Tags: shell, awk

I want to calculate the average of 15 files:- ifile1.txt, ifile2.txt, ....., ifile15.txt. Number of columns and rows of each file are same, but having different type of missing values (for instance ?, -9999 & 8888). Part of the data looks as

```
 ifile1.txt             ifile2.txt               ifile3.txt
 2  8888   ?     ? .    1  2     1     3    .    5  ?  ?  ? .
 1  -9999  8888  ? .    1  8888  8888  8888 .    5  ?  ?  ? .
 4  6      5     2 .    2  5     5     1    .    3  4  3  1 .
 5  5      7     1 .    0  0     1     1    .    4  3  4  0 .
 .  .      .     . .    .  .     .     .    .    .  .  .  . .
```

I would like to find a new file which will show the average of these 15 fils without considering the missing values.

```
 ofile.txt
 2.66     2        1         3      . (i.e. average of 2 1 5, average of 8888 2 ? and so on)
 2.33     -9999    -9999    -9999   .
 3        5        4.33      1.33   .
 3        2.66     4         0.66   .
 .      .     .    .      .
```

This question is similar to my earlier question [Average of multiple files without considering missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33255680/average-of-multiple-files-without-considering-missing-values)

I was trying with the following, but not getting the desired result.

```
awk '
   {
     for (i = 1;i <= NF;i++) {
     Sum[FNR,i]+=$i
     Count[FNR,i]+=$i!="?|-9999|8888"
   }
     }
  END {
       for( i = 1; i <= FNR; i++){
       for( j = 1; j <= NF; j++) printf "%s ", Count[i,j] != 0 ? Sum[i,j]/Count[i,j] : "?|-9999|8888"
       print "-9999"
      }
     }
   ' ifile*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i !~ /^([?]|-9999|8888)$/) {
            Count[FNR,i]++
            Sum[FNR,i]+=$i
        }
  }
}
END {
   for (i=1; i<=FNR;i++){
       for (j=1; j<=NF; j++)
           printf "%12.2f ", Count[i,j]!=0 ? Sum[i,j]/Count[i,j] : -9999
       print ""
   }
}
' ifile*.txt
```

This produces:

```
    2.67         2.00         1.00         3.00 
    2.33     -9999.00     -9999.00     -9999.00 
    3.00         5.00         4.33         1.33 
    3.00         2.67         4.00         0.67
```

Comment: I think, here is a repeatition of 8888. Will `-9999|8888|8888` be  `-9999|8888`

Comment: @Kayan Yes, you are right: that was superfluous.  I have removed it now.