# Compute sum for column 2 and average for all other columns in multiple files without considering missing values

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I want to calculate the sum for column 2 and average for all other columns from 15 files:- ifile1.txt, ifile2.txt, ....., ifile15.txt. Number of columns and rows of each file are same. But some of them are missing values. Part of the data looks as

```
 ifile1.txt      ifile2.txt       ifile3.txt
 3  ?  ?  ? .    1  2  1  3 .    4  ?  ?  ? .
 1  ?  ?  ? .    1  ?  ?  ? .    5  ?  ?  ? .
 4  6  5  2 .    2  5  5  1 .    3  4  3  1 .
 5  5  7  1 .    0  0  1  1 .    4  3  4  0 .
 .  .  .  . .    .  .  .  . .    .  .  .  . .
```

I would like to find a new file which will show the sum for column 2 and average for all other columns from these 15 fils without considering the missing values.

```
 ofile.txt
 2.66   2     1    3      . (i.e. average of 3 1 4, sum of ? 2 ?, average of ? 1 ?, average of ? 3 ?, and so on)
 2.33   ?     ?    ?      .
 3      15    4.33 1.33   .
 3      8     4    0.66   .
 .      .     .    .      .
```

This question is similar to my earlier question [Average of multiple files without considering missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33255680/average-of-multiple-files-without-considering-missing-values) where the script was written for average for all columns.

```
awk '
   {
   for (i = 1;i <= NF;i++) {
      Sum[FNR,i]+=$i
      Count[FNR,i]+=$i!="?"
      }
   }
END {
   for( i = 1; i <= FNR; i++){
      for( j = 1; j <= NF; j++) printf "%s ", Count[i,j] != 0 ? Sum[i,j]/Count[i,j] : "?"
      print ""
      }
   }
' ifile*
```

But I can't able to modify it to my desire output.

Comment: I notice that the average values are not rounded up, is that what you want?

Comment: @CWLiu . Yes.. I need with %.2f

Comment: Don't add `...`s to any sample input/output you provide - it adds no value, just obfuscates your question and means we need to then manually remove it before we can test a possible solution. `%.2f` rounds up whereas your posted output shows rounding down so `%.2f` is not what you need (or your posted expected output is wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your previous `awk` script, I modify it as followed,

```
$ cat awk_script
{
  for (i = 1;i <= NF;i++) {
    Sum[FNR,i]+=$i
    Count[FNR,i]+=$i!="?"                                                                                                                                                                                    
  }
}
END {
  for( i = 1; i <= FNR; i++){
    for( j = 1; j <= NF; j++) 
      if(j==2) { printf "%s\t" ,Count[i,j] != 0 ? Sum[i,j] : "?" }                                                                                                                                           
      else { 
        if (Count[i,j] != 0){ 
          val=Sum[i,j]/Count[i,j]
          printf "%s%s\t",int(val),match(val,/\.[0-9]/)!=0 ? "."substr(val,RSTART+1,2):""
        } else printf "?\t" 
      }   
    print ""
  }
}
```

And the output would be:

```
$ awk -f awk_script ifile*
2.66    2       1       3       0
2.33    ?       ?       ?       0
3       15      4.33    1.33    0
3       8       4       0.66    0
0       0       0       0       0
```

Brief explanation,

- `if(j==2)`: print the sum of the value in each file
- for the average value, I notice that the values are not rounded up, so extract the decimal part using `substr(val,RSTART+1,2)`, and integer part using `int(val)`

Comment: Thank you very much. However, the boarder dot "." is confusing me. I just put them because there are more columns and rows. I was trying to modify `/\.[0-9]/)` but getting errors. Would you please remove those dots.

Comment: @Kay, I have modified the answer for you. Check that.

Comment: Thank you very much... I have no vote today.. all 40 vote finished.. I will give a vote tomorrow..

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { dfltVal="?"; OFS="\t" }
{
    for (colNr=1; colNr<=NF; colNr++) {
        if ($colNr != dfltVal) {
            sum[FNR,colNr] += $colNr
            cnt[FNR,colNr]++
        }
    }
}
END {
    for (rowNr=1; rowNr<=FNR; rowNr++) {
        for (colNr=1; colNr<=NF; colNr++) {
            val = dfltVal
            if ( cnt[rowNr,colNr] != 0 ) {
                val = int(100 * sum[rowNr,colNr] / (colNr==2 ? 1 : cnt[rowNr,colNr])) / 100
            }
            printf "%s%s", val, (colNr<NF ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2 file3
2.66    2       1       3
2.33    ?       ?       ?
3       15      4.33    1.33
3       8       4       0.66
```